# Terminated thead with delayed deletion

Tags: multithreading, cpu, context-switch

i have a general question. We are postponing the deletion of terminated threads with say 10 minutes. Those threads are not running, they are sent to something like a garbage collector which takes care of deleting them after the specified time elapses and joining it to the main thread. My question is can those threads still content for resources i.e., can we have context switching caused by them?

Answer (score 1):

Since each `Thread` is terminated (i.e. `Thread.IsAlive`evals to `false`), the scheduler will not care about them anymore. I wonder however, what the reason for your approach is. Why wouldn't using the ThreadPool work for you, instead of house-keeping Threads yourself?

Comment: The ASP.Net thread pool is full of flaws and weaknesses. There are many situations where a custom thread pool is the only way to go. Having said that, 10 minutes is extremely long.